# Erro ao salvar dados com EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relatório, testes-de-unidade

Estou montando meus testes unitários e tentado salva os dados em uma tabela usando o Entity Framework, mas na hora que executo me retorna um erro.

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See
>   'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> em System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()    em
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()    em
>   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()    em
>   CarrinhoDeCompras.Infra.Data.EF.Repositorios.RepositorioBase`1.Add(TEntity
>   obj) na C:\WORK\1-Arquivos
>   Pessoais\CarrinhoDeCompras\CarrinhoDeCompras.Infra.Data.EF\Repositorios\RepositorioBase.cs:linha
>   17    em CarrinhoDeCompras.Application.Test.OrdersTest.InclirPedidos()
>   na C:\WORK\1-Arquivos
>   Pessoais\CarrinhoDeCompras\CarrinhoDeCompras.Application.Test\OrdersTest.cs:linha
>   53

Analisado vi que o EF parece que esta tentando fazer um insert em uma tabela de dependência da que estou tentando inserir os dados.

```
using CarrinhoDeCompras.Domain.Entidades;
using CarrinhoDeCompras.Domain.Interfaces.Repositorios;
using CarrinhoDeCompras.Infra.Data.EF.Repositorios;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;

namespace CarrinhoDeCompras.Application.Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class OrdersTest
    {
        private  IRepositorioOrders _repositorio;
        [TestMethod]
        public void InclirPedidos()
        {
            var order = new Orders()
            {
                CustomerID = 85,
                Customer = "VINET",
                EmployeeID = 5,
                OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
                RequiredDate = DateTime.Now,
                ShippedDate = DateTime.Now,
                ShipVia = 3,
                Freight = 13,
                ShipName = "Vins et alcools Chevalier",
                ShipAddress = "59 rue de l'Abbaye",
                ShipCity = "Reims",
                ShipPostalCode = "51100",
                ShipCountry = "France",
            };


            try
            {
                _repositorio = new RepositorioOrders();
                _repositorio.Add(order);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Como pode ver estou passando os IDs das tabelas de dependências como o `CustomerID = 85,` , mas mesmo assim ele esta reclamando desse campo.

Minha classes Orders.

```
public partial class Orders
    {
        public Orders()
        {
            this.OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetails>();
            this.Employees = new Employees();
            this.Customers = new Customers();
            this.Shippers = new Shippers();
        }

        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public int? CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string Customer { get; set; }
        public int? EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? RequiredDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ShippedDate { get; set; }
        public int ShipVia { get; set; }
        public decimal? Freight { get; set; }
        public string ShipName { get; set; }
        public string ShipAddress { get; set; }
        public string ShipCity { get; set; }
        public string ShipRegion { get; set; }
        public string ShipPostalCode { get; set; }
        public string ShipCountry { get; set; }
        public virtual Customers Customers { get; set; }
        public virtual Employees Employees { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual Shippers Shippers { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: No Mapping do EF falta vc mandar ele Ignorar a propriedade ValidationResults. :)

Comment: Veja aqui: https://github.com/thiagolunardi/MvcMusicStoreDDD/blob/abc8a02506dd05bbc6ea40cc81d7c5b2ecea0817/MvcMusicStore.Data.Context/Mapping/OrderMap.cs#L56

Comment: não, vou implementa aqui para ver.

Comment: Muita coisa para implementa para usar o o seu ValidationResults

Comment: So mandar o EF ignorar as propriedades que não para persistir.

Comment: tentei fazer isso mas ... The navigation property 'Orders' is not a declared property on type 'Customers'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid navigation property.